# Enumerate multiple select boxes from a single array - NgFor.?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Here is what I want to do.
I have an array of objects like this..

```
[
{productOptionId: 1, value: "Black"},
{productOptionId: 1, value: "Red"},
{productOptionId: 2, value: "UK 43"},
{productOptionId: 2, value: "FIJI 1"},
]
```

I want to group elements of this array based on 'productOptionId' and display select-boxes based on those groups. And also use those sub-arrays to display options of those respective select boxes.

Typescript code :

```
var i=0;
var result = [];

  var object = [];
  var objects = [
{productOptionId: 1, value: "Black"},
{productOptionId: 1, value: "Red"},
{productOptionId: 2, value: "UK 43"},
{productOptionId: 2, value: "FIJI 1"},
];
  var k = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
    if(k!=objects[i].productOptionId){
      k = objects[i].productOptionId;
      object = []
      object.push(objects[i]);
      result.push(Array.from(object));
    }else{
      object.push(objects[i]);
    }
  }

this.allOptionValues = Array.from(result);
```

Html code :

```
<p *ngFor="let productOption of allOptionValues" >
  <select >
    <option   *ngFor="let optionValue of productOption.values" >{{optionValue.value}}</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Expected output :

[image]

Comment: Your `[
0: {productOptionId: 1, value: "Black"}
1: {productOptionId: 1, value: "Red"}
2: {productOptionId: 2, value: "UK 43"}
3: {productOptionId: 2, value: "FIJI 1"}
]` looks invalid can you create demo in https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @Justcode I copied it from the console. Edited the answer to reflect the actual javascript array.

Comment: Doesn't seems relative because your loop is on `this.product.productVariants` and inside that you are using `variant.productOptionValues` can you post actual array and explain what you are trying to do in loop?

Answer (score 0):

### html

```
<p *ngFor="let productOption of allOptionValues | keyvalue">
    <select>
        <option   *ngFor="let optionValue of productOption.value" >{{optionValue.value}}</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

### ts

```
constructor() {
    this.makeProductGroup();
}

makeProductGroup() {
    var objects = [
        {productOptionId: 1, value: "Black"},
        {productOptionId: 1, value: "Red"},
        {productOptionId: 2, value: "UK 43"},
        {productOptionId: 2, value: "FIJI 1"},
    ];
    const newProductArray = {};
    const uniqueProductId = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if (uniqueProductId.indexOf(objects[i].productOptionId) === -1) {
            uniqueProductId.push(objects[i].productOptionId);
            newProductArray[objects[i].productOptionId] = [];
        }
        newProductArray[objects[i].productOptionId].push(objects[i]);
    }
    this.allOptionValues = newProductArray;    
}
```

makeProductGroup() function make OBJECT like below one so we use keyvalue pipe for loop in object.

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "productOptionId": 1,
      "value": "Black"
    },
    {
      "productOptionId": 1,
      "value": "Red"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "productOptionId": 2,
      "value": "UK 43"
    },
    {
      "productOptionId": 2,
      "value": "FIJI 1"
    }
  ]
}
```